# Positioning of a DIV using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have to create a format for my web application which is the given in the image below.Using CSS only, I styled my-ad div as shown in the picture.

[image]
There is a 10px padding from the border for the word "Hello Coder" and the font of which has to be in "Tahoma"
Here is my code which I tried but was getting an error with the font family tahoma and the border width.

```css
#my-div{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  font-family:tahoma;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my-div"> Hello Coders 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every thing is similar to your drawing except border-width. Do you really need it?

Comment: yes I need the border width as it is the requirement of my application. May I know whats wrong with the border width?

Comment: You drew nothing in your drawing about border. Would you  please say again what is wrong with current output?

Comment: i am not able to use the font tahoma.

Comment: using chrome or firefox inspect element and check for computed style. Tahoma is a global font and it should be displayed correctly.

Comment: Tahoma is with uppercase - font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; https://www.cssfontstack.com/Tahoma